# How can I map the Caps Lock key to ShiftInsert on xubuntu

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard-shortcuts

For a long time I have disabled my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key using `xmodmap`.  However I would now like to map it to something useful, specifically <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> which does the same as the mouse middle button (if you have one).

I don't think this can be done simply with `xmodmap` because I don't think you can generate a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+key directly.

Can anyone suggest a simple way of doing what I want?

Comment: The key thing in my question is how to map the Caps Lock key to a *Shifted* key.  All the 'duplicates' don't do this as far as I can see,